# Beginner making a Console based RPG in C#, having some problems with room navigation

Tags: c#, console-application

What I've implemented so far: Command-based movement for North, East, South, and West, Look Command for room description, Help Command for instructions, and 5 rooms shaped in a plus sign for testing.
Right now, I'm trying to make it so the player can't move in a direction if there is no room their. My solution works fine for linear movement, but if the player goes north, then west, they are able to enter a non-existent room, and the compiler throws an exception the next time it tries to calculate a movement because the current room is null. For some reason, my room detection isn't completely functional.
Here's my code:

Main:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Room currentRoom;
        List<Room> rooms = new List<Room>();
        Player player = new Player();

        //Rooms
        Room startingRoom = new Room("Starting room", "This is the starting room", 0, 0);
        Room northRoom = new Room("North room", "This is the north room", 0, 1);
        Room northMostRoom = new Room("North room", "This is the north room", 0, 2);
        Room eastRoom = new Room("East room", "This is the east room", 1, 0);
        Room southRoom = new Room("South room", "This is the south room", 0, -1);
        Room westRoom = new Room("West room", "This is the west room", -1, 0);

        //Add and set starting room as current room
        rooms.Add(startingRoom);
        currentRoom = startingRoom;

        //Adding rooms
        rooms.Add(northRoom);
        rooms.Add(northMostRoom);
        rooms.Add(eastRoom);
        rooms.Add(southRoom);
        rooms.Add(westRoom);

        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Dungeon. This is the starting room.");
        GetHelp();
        Console.WriteLine("There are four exits. Which way do you want to go?");
        while (true)
        {
            HandleInput(player, ref currentRoom, rooms);
        }



    }

    private static void GetHelp()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You can move to locations by entering 'North', 'East', 'South', and 'West'.");
        Console.WriteLine("You can also examine the room by entering 'Look'.");
        Console.WriteLine("Type 'Help' at any time to view instructions.");
    }

    private static Room SetCurrentRoom(List<Room> rooms, Player player)
    {
        foreach (var room in rooms)
        {
            if (room.XPos == player.PlayerXPos && room.YPos == player.PlayerYPos)
            {
                return room;
            }

        }
        return null;

    }

    private static void HandleInput(Player player, ref Room currentRoom, List<Room> rooms)
    {
        var input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (input == "North")
        {
            if (CheckIfRoomToNorth(currentRoom, rooms))
            {
                player.Move(Direction.Directions.North);
                currentRoom = SetCurrentRoom(rooms, player);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot move north.");
            }


        }
        else if (input == "East")
        {
            if (CheckIfRoomToEast(currentRoom, rooms))
            {
                player.Move(Direction.Directions.East);
                currentRoom = SetCurrentRoom(rooms, player);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot move to east.");
            }
        }
        else if (input == "South")
        {
            if (CheckIfRoomToSouth(currentRoom, rooms))
            {
                player.Move(Direction.Directions.South);
                currentRoom = SetCurrentRoom(rooms, player);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot move to south.");
            }

        }
        else if (input == "West")
        {
            if (CheckIfRoomToWest(currentRoom, rooms))
            {
                player.Move(Direction.Directions.West);
                currentRoom = SetCurrentRoom(rooms, player);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot move to west.");
            }

        }

        else if (input == "Help")
        {
            GetHelp();
        }
        else if (input == "Look")
        {
            var currentRoomDescription = currentRoom.RoomDescription;
            Console.WriteLine(currentRoomDescription);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input.");
        }

    }

    private static bool CheckIfRoomToNorth(Room currentRoom, List<Room> rooms)
    {
        foreach (var room in rooms)
        {
            if (currentRoom.YPos == (room.YPos - 1))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    private static bool CheckIfRoomToEast(Room currentRoom, List<Room> rooms)
    {
        foreach (var room in rooms)
        {
            if (currentRoom.XPos == (room.XPos - 1))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    private static bool CheckIfRoomToSouth(Room currentRoom, List<Room> rooms)
    {
        foreach (var room in rooms)
        {
            if (currentRoom.YPos == (room.YPos + 1))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    private static bool CheckIfRoomToWest(Room currentRoom, List<Room> rooms)
    {
        foreach (var room in rooms)
        {
            if (currentRoom.XPos == (room.XPos + 1))
            {
                return true;

            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Player:

```
public class Player
{
    public int Health { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PlayerXPos { get; set; }
    public int PlayerYPos { get; set; }

    public void Move(Direction.Directions direction)
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
            case Direction.Directions.North:
                PlayerYPos += 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Moving north");
                break;
            case Direction.Directions.East:
                PlayerXPos += 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Moving east.");
                break;
            case Direction.Directions.South:
                PlayerYPos -= 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Moving south.");
                break;
            case Direction.Directions.West:
                PlayerXPos -= 1;
                Console.WriteLine("Moving west.");
                break;

        }
    }


}
```

Direction:

```
public class Direction
{
    public enum Directions
    {
        North,
        East,
        South,
        West
    }
}
```

Room:

```
    public class Room
{
    public string RoomName { get; set; }
    public string RoomDescription { get; set; }
    public int XPos { get; set; }
    public int YPos { get; set; }

    public Room(string roomName, string roomDescription, int xPos, int yPos)
    {
        this.RoomName = roomName;
        this.RoomDescription = roomDescription;
        this.XPos = xPos;
        this.YPos = yPos;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're on the right lines. You might need to have a class that holds all of the state of the game. It could be something like this (just a rough pseudo code to get you started).

```
public class Dungeon() 
{
  public List<Room> Rooms {get; set;}
  public Player Player {get; set;}

  public void AddRoom(Room room) 
  {
    // add rooms in here - can check none have overlapping coordinates
    if (noOverlap) 
    {
      Rooms.Add(room);
    }
  }

  public void MovePlayer(Direction direction)
  {
     // get the new coordinates if the player moves
     // check the list of rooms to see if there is one there
     if (roomExists) 
     {
        Player.Move(direction);
     }
     else
     {
       throw new Exception("No room to move to");
     }
  }
}
```

You need something that knows about both the current position of your player, as well as the rooms that are available to be able to check if a movement is valid, hence the need for a class for the game. You can handle the exception in the main game loop and inform the user.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. When checking for rooms, I was only checking once coordinate.This made it consider all rooms as valid rooms fi they fit that one criteria.